# How to add a keymap for a visual mode plugin command and pass it the visually-selected range?

Tags: neovim, key-bindings, visual-mode, range

I have the [linediff.vim plugin](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/linediff.vim) installed. Its main command `:Linediff` only works for visual mode, to which I'd like to add a keymap for this command.

I'm using Neovim's Lua API, so I tried this:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('x', '<leader>ld', "<Cmd>'<,'>Linediff<CR>")
```

But when I try to use it, I get the error `E20: Mark not set`.

I also experimented with using `nvim_create_user_command()` to try and achieve this, but didn't really get anywhere as I ran into various errors due to not fully grokking its API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vim I think you would do

```
xnoremap <leader>ld :LineDiff<enter>
```

taking advantage of `:` inserting marks. The problem with `<Cmd>` is it *doesn’t* switch modes… so probably `:` is the right thing to do here.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot!